# Laravel Request returning load balancer ip instead of client ip

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing an issue while getting the client ip address, when I try

```
request()->ip()
```

It returns me private server IP instead of client IP.

What can be a possible reason how to avoid this.

The reason behind asking this question is my payment gateway need a public IP to accept payments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually found a solution which worked on all environments written in official documentation of Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies).

There is middleware called trusted proxies `App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies`.

This middleware is responsible for resolving the proxies, it has a property called `proxies`.

I just set the `proxies` property as array of private IP's and it worked.

This is how it should looks like after modification.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string
     */
    protected $proxies = [
        'x.x.x.x',
    ];

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

Don't forget to replace `x.x.x.x` with your private IP.

Now when I called the following function

```
request()->ip();
```

It gave me expected result.

Comment: To confirm, `x.x.x.x` should be the private IP of the load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
request()->header('X-Forwarded-For')
```

and check how your load balancer configured, maybe you forget about Original IP and X-Forwarded-For headers

Comment: Thanks @Dry7 I tried this way and It solved the issue on production but on local and testing ENV its returning null.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this, I had a DO load balancer, which wasn't sending any headers containing the IP in the first place, so I had to enable the proxy protocol on the LB first and then I was able to configure nginx to accept proxy protocol and convert the LB IP to original client IP at nginx level, following this. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/

After that the request()->ip() was returning the original client IP instead of LB IP, hope this helps someone.